# PHP mail showing text without link

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, email

I'm making a small project for my courses, and I need to send a mail with HTML content. Because it needs to be customised, I use an AJAX function to send it with data, via a PHP script. The problem is that when I receive the mail, it doesn't show me a link with href, but only the content of the link.

Here's my sending code in the PHP script :

```php
$msg = $_POST["message"];
$objet = $_POST["objet"];
$passage_ligne = "\n";
$header = "From: no-reply@pleasepayme.ch\r\n";
$header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
$header .= 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable';
mail($emailDestinataire,$objet,$msg,$header);
```

Here's the AJAX function calling it :

```js
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'sendMail.php',
    data:{
        email: $("#connEmail").val(),
        message : '<html><head><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /></head><body>Cliquez <a href="https://pleasepayme.ch/index.php?email='+$("#connEmail").val()+'&token='+response[0].token+'">ici</a> pour vous connecter<br/>Votre code de connexion est : '+response[0].token+'</body></html>',
        objet: "Token de connexion pleasepayme.ch",
    },
    success:function(response){
        alert(response);
        return false;
    }
});
```

And here's the mail I get :

[image]

Please help me ;)

Comment: any error in browser console while hitting Ajax request. As well as what's the output of `var_dump($msg);` at your php end? show us

Comment: Hey tks I checked but it's exactly the same content :/

Comment: Salut, can you try to remove $header .= 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable'; from your Header? I use this in my code and always got it working:

$header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$header .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";

Comment: Hey, tks I usually too do without, but here without it, the mail isn't sent...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I've found the problem, thanks to Michael T for making me watch the `$header .= 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable;` line, it was the problem.
I changed it to `$header .= 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8BIT';` and now it works well. Thank you for trying to help me ^^

Comment: Plaisir mate! Thumbs up!